# Is there a fixed integer $x>1$ satisfing ${\sigma}^{k}(x)\equiv 0\pmod{x}$ for all positive integers $k$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples, congruences, alternative-proof

This question related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1357465/230303) question from SE. I'm interested to know if there exists an integer $x>1$ that satisfies $${\sigma}^{k}(x)\equiv 0\pmod{x}$$
for all positive integers $k$.

**Note.** $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of divisors of $x$, and ${\sigma}^{k}(x )=\sigma(\sigma(\sigma(\sigma(\cdots x))))$ is $\sigma$ iterated $k$ times.

**Edit.** I edited the question to avoid the trivialities.

Comment: There are also multiperfect numbers.  I suspect there is a proof that metaperfect numbers (infinitely iterated form of multiperfects) do not exist.  Gerhard "Likes Using The Term 'Metaperfect'" Paseman, 2015.07.14

Comment: I suspect that such an $x$ does not exist, but proving it will be very hard.

Comment: @GHfromMO, I think should be for x to be perfect number for all k and this is very hard

Comment: @Ricardo Andrade, thank you for your edition to the question

Comment: @Ricardo Andrade, do you have any counter example for the above question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to collect some basic observations and references for the benefit
of future readers.

A more challenging problem is to ask for integers $m$ and $p$ such that for all
integers $k$, $p_0 = p, p_{k+1}=\sigma(p_k),$ and $p_k = 0 \bmod m$.  The current
problem adds the restriction that $p=m$, which implies $m$ is a multiperfect number.
Since multiperfect numbers are rare, it should be hard to find a **metaperfect**
number, a number $m$ that satisfies $\sigma^k(m) = 0 \bmod m$ for all iterations
of $\sigma$.

Indeed, $\sigma(m) \lt m\omega(m)$ for most values of $m$, so for a potentially
metaperfect number to exist, we can't depend on $\sigma(p_k)/m$ to be coprime
to $m$ for very many $k$.  More likely, $\sigma(p_k)/m$, if integral, will share 
a small factor with $m$ and further iterations of $\sigma$ will avoid certain large 
prime factors of $m$.  This is what was observed, and what I hoped to prove and 
did not in the other answer.

It is an interesting side question to determine $\min_k g_k$ where
$g_0=p_0$ and $g_{k+1} = \gcd(p_{k+1},g_k)$.  In particular, do the iterates of
$\sigma$ encounter a square or twice a square, regardless of the starting point?
If so, then the minimum is odd and likely 1.  Otherwise $p$ is a seed for $m$, and
$p$ might be useful in looking for multiperfect numbers which are multiples of $m$.

Cohen and te Riele investigated a weaker question: Given $n$ is there a $k$ for
which $\sigma^k(n) = 0 \mod n$?  They did this in a 1996 paper and asserted through
computation that the answer was yes for $n \leq 400$.  Their data suggest to me both
that the weaker question has an affirmative answer, and that there are no
metaperfect numbers or even seeds for a number.

Regarding Gerry Myerson's example in a comment, I think one can construct arbitrarily
long finite sequences $p_k$ which satisfy the congruence conditions, but to find such
$p$ with $p=m$ will result in very large values even for $k$ as small as $3$.  Toward
this end, there is a 2009 paper of Katai that I have not found but think will be useful
in this study.

I recommend as a starting point for a reference search

Cohen, Graeme L., and Herman JJ te Riele. "Iterating the sum-of-divisors function."

Experimental Mathematics 5.2 (1996): 91-100.

and (if you can get it)

Kátai, I. "On the prime power divisors of the iterates of \phi(n) and \sigma(n), Šiauliai

Math." Semin 4.12 (2009): 125-143.

Gerhard "Not Quite A Research Announcement" Paseman, 2015.07.21

Comment: Curiously, the MR entry for the Katai paper discusses only iterates of $\phi$, and never mentions $\sigma$. The paper appears to be freely available at http://siauliaims.su.lt/pdfai/2009/Katai-09.pdf

Comment: Wow @Gerry, thanks for the link!  I will peruse the paper more closely, but on first skimming, I don't see any remarks that say the paper's results apply to $\sigma$.  I do find a 1991 paper on $\omega$ that looks interesting though.  Gerhard "Deeper Into The Rabbit Hole" Paseman, 2015.07.21

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 2015.07.15** I believe there is no such integer $x$.  See below for the rest of the edit.  **END EDIT 2015.07.15**

I had some initial thoughts which seemed promising.  They do not lead to a proof, but (with notation below) may show that $m$ must be very large indeed for even $m_1$ and $m_2$ to be multiples of $m$.  I suspect $m_3$ will never be a multiple of $m$ in such an unlikely situation.

I prefer to use $m$ for $x$:  this is because $\sigma(m) = 0 \bmod m$ means $m$ is a multiply perfect number.  To avoid trivialities I assume $m \gt 1$.

Note that $\sigma(m)/m$ is bounded above by the product over all primes $q$ dividing $m$ of $q/(q-1)$, which is $O(\log p)$ with $p$ the largest prime divisor of $m$, and strictly less than $p$ when $p \gt 3$.  (Indeed, it is less than $\omega(m)$, the number of distinct prime divisors of $m$, when $\omega(m) \gt 4$.)  While $\sigma(m)$ itself does not have to be multiperfect, I suspect there are finitely many numbers with $\sigma(\sigma(m))$ a multiple of $m$.  In particular, let $g_0=m_0=m$, $m_{n+1}=\sigma(m_n)$, and $g_{n+1}=\gcd(g_n,m_{n+1})$.  I suspect $g_3 \lt m$.  I base this suspicion on the observation that the power of $2$ exactly dividing $m_n$ appears to change between $m_n, m_{n+1}$, and $m_{n+2}$.

Let me write $w$ for $\omega(m)$ and let us note that for a multiperfect $m$, $m_1$ will
differ from $m$ by having less than $O(\log(w))$ additional prime factors, some in common with the prime factors of $m$.  So the prime factorization of $m_1$ looks very much like the prime factorization of $m$.

I would like to argue that the prime factorization of $m_2$ should be quite different from that of $m_1$, because any additional powers of $q$ for $q$ a small prime dividing $n$ will affect $\sigma(q^n)$ and thus remove some prime factors.  However, it is possible that there are (insanely large) odd multiperfect numbers which would be factors of $m$ and not be affected by this.  Indeed, this question may be equivalent to the question of the existence of large odd multiperfect numbers.

**EDIT (Part II) 2015.07.15**
Let us look at $S(m)= \sigma(m)/m$.  Letting the following products run over the distinct
primes $q$ dividing $m$, we have $\prod (q+1)/q \leq S(m) \lt \prod q/(q-1)$.  (And the lower bound is at least half the upper bound, so we have $S(m) \simeq \prod q/(q-1)$.)  As observed above, $S(m) \lt \omega(m)$ when $4 < \omega(m)$ and $S(m) \lt 2\omega(m)$ the rest of the time. So $S(m)$ is pretty small compared to $m$ and often small compared to $\log p$ where $p$ is the greatest prime factor of $m$.

Let $r_n = m_{n+1}/m_n = S(m_n)$.  The assumption in the problem implies $r_n \gt r_0$,
for if $m$ properly divides $k$ then $S(m) \lt S(k)$.  Then $m_n \gt mr_0^n$ for all $n$, since $m_n$ is an increasing sequence.  I believe we can't have both conditions hold indefinitely.  However, I now switch ground on
my assertion above that $g_3 < m$ always happens: I think it can, I just don't think we will see an example with fewer than a 1000 decimal digits (which isn't insanely large).

Gerry Myerson's example from the comment is thought provoking: When $S(m)$ is coprime to $m$, we clearly have $m  \mid m_2$ as well as $m \mid  m_1$, and by multiplicativity of $S$ we also have $S(S(m)m)=S(S(m))S(m)$.  What if $S(m)$ is not coprime to $m$?
We still have $S(S(m)m) \lt S(m)S(S(m))$.

This last is the crux. $S()$ grows slower than $\log()$, so we need to show this
contradicts the growth rate implied by all $m_n$ being multiples of $m$. It is this
that inspires my confidence above, and also has me reverse my stance on this being
equivalent to odd multiperfect numbers.  I hope to finish this argument in a future
edit.
**END EDIT(Part II) 2015.07.15**

Gerhard "Doesn't Have A Good Closer" Paseman, 2015.07.14

Comment: The number $n=13188979363639752997731839211623940096$ satisfies $\sigma(n)=5n$ and, since $\gcd(5,n)=1$, $$\sigma^2(n)=\sigma(5n)=6\sigma(n)=30n$$ so at least there's one example where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are multiples of $m$. Whether $n$ qualifies as "very large indeed" is a matter of taste.

Comment: That is smaller than I would have expected.  Gerhard "How About One More Iterate?" Paseman, 2015.07.15

Comment: I am now confident the answer to the question is no; the basic reason is that the function $r(m)=\sigma(m)/m$ "can't grow fast enough" to support the existence of such a number.  I will attempt an argument.  Gerhard "Sleeping On It Is Good" Paseman, 2015.07.15

Comment: @GerryMyerson, if you seek to the asymptotics integer , i think 114 mod 6 is good example and fails only for k=9,12,18

Comment: @zeraouliarafik  But that is a different question: you are now asking for an integer m and integer x such that $x$ divides $\sigma^k(m)$ for all $k$.  It may be possible that 2 is such an integer, but even that is not known.  Gerhard "This Question Is Hard Enough" Paseman, 2015.07.15

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, if you see it that is not standard and make a new  problem , can we do a paper about this topic ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik,  I'm not sure.  I would be happy to be acknowledged for my contributions should you wish to write such a paper.  I can be pretty picky about style in something that has my name as author though.  However, people have studied iterates of $\sigma()$ before;  If you want my help with such a paper, my first question would be to get the bibliography of papers you have read on the subject, and my second would be for the list of papers you have skimmed or intend to skim.  Gerhard "Acknowledging The Literature Is Important" Paseman, 2015.07.15

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, ok no problem , give me your Email to i can contact you and i'm just in the paper as Author who stated the problem .

Comment: $\sigma^{32}(2)=564210119465811\equiv1\bmod2$. I don't think it has been proved that $\sigma^k(2)\equiv0\bmod2$ for all $k\ge33$. Data at http://oeis.org/A007497/b007497.txt

Comment: @zeraouliarafik for permission to email me on this, you have it. For the email address, you have to do (a small amount of) research.  Gerhard "Hint: Try The User Page" Paseman, 2015.07.15

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: please delete your last comment.  I present my personal information the way I do to keep a low profile.  Gerhard "Doesn't Need Spambots Knowing It" Paseman, 2015.07.15

Comment: @GerhardPaseman , sorry i don't know i deleted it excuse me

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, can I accept the answer or should be waite the complet proof ?

Comment: I think you should not accept this version.  I am thinking about a proof, as well as related questions (which you should think about as well).  If there is no further progress, I will add a further edit which says what difficulties there are in showing that such a sequence exists.  If you find the result acceptable, it would be OK with me to accept that future version.  Gerhard "Now Back To The Present" Paseman, 2015.07.16

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, I read many papers about multiperfect number but i think this is make a new problem ,i can't find any equivalence to this question " it is very hard"

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: pleas look this:Theorem 2.3 :https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL9/Shparlinski/shpar43.pdf, i think it works with integer 2

Comment: I recommend further discussion in email, not comments.  Also, it is unclear how the paper relates to the problem.  Iterates of the totient function are not necessarily related to iterates of the sigma function.  Gerhard "You Can Explain In Email" Paseman, 2015.07.16

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, I have send to you some related papers to this problem "check email" !!!!

Comment: It is known that sigma(n)/n can't grow too fast:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Approximate_growth_rate Robin also proved, unconditionally, that the inequality

    $\ \sigma(n) < e^\gamma n \log \log n + \frac{0.6483\ n}{\log \log n} $ holds for all n ≥ 3.

Comment: well , then the question abouve may equivalent to Riemann Hypothesis according to your comments

Comment: @zeraouliarafik I don't think so. The inequality is unconditional and RH is equivalent to another inequality.

Comment: @joro, I understand according to ur above comment that it's impossible to get a such number X satasfing the problem

Comment: @GerryMyerson, you can check also this number :$n={114}^{114k}$, for $k$ is a positive integer .

Comment: @zeraouliarafik , I recommend that you no longer comment on this answer; it is getting too long to follow.  Also, you should check that such n do not satisfy your condition: \sigma(114^(114k)) is odd.  Further, I do not want to be emailed on conjectural statements.  You should show that you put in some work to resolve a question you have.  Gerhard "Look At Twice A Square" Paseman, 2015.07.20

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, ok thank you very much for this observation

Comment: @GerhardPaseman,This type of problems is beyond the actual theory.and should study the superperfect number not metaperfect number .

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, The solution of that problem in this paper :Dieter Bode, Über eine Verallgemeinerung der vollkommenen Zahlen, Dissertation, Braunschweig, 1971. , but i can't get it , and it's stated that no even m-superperfect existed for m\geq 3